# Кодировка в Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, кодировка, перекодировка

Я писал код на windows 10 в visual stduio 2017, позже перенес `.cpp'шник` на Ubuntu, где и запускал, но столкнулся с такой проблемой: gcc копилирует код без ошибок , однако неправильно интерпретирует и выводит символы текста, но не цифр. В какую кодировку нужно конвертировать для Ubuntu. И какая кодировка используется в Ubuntu ?

Comment: utf-8, если кратко

Comment: посмотрите сами: `$ locale` (@Fat-Zer, ответ у вас — неправильный)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, почему не 16 ?

Comment: @Elvin потому что это не windows

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, знаю, но, сам понимаешь, если встретить человека с отличной кодировкой, то первая реакция — крайнее удивление, а вторая — подколы про криокамеру и обвинения межнациональной розни ;)... а если придираться, то вывод `locale` ещё не говорит, в какой кодировке работает терминал...  и дабы не расписывать всё это, оговорки «если кратко» вполне достаточно...

Comment: @Elvin, не совместима с ASCII, совместимость с которой требуют всякие POSIX'ы...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, у вас у всех ответ неправильный. Локаль — это свойство **процесса**, а не системы. Команда `locale` выдаёт то, в чём работает оболочка (процесс оболочки).